# Compare 3 arrays to find patterns and format output

Tags: python, arrays

I have 3 arrays with same customer names in different orders, what I am trying to do and the following:

1 - Take the name of customers and compare to return when it is the same, thus solving the problem of random order;

2 - After obtaining this comparison, the output should be as follows:

```
Result: CLIENT1, '2', '3', '2', '3', '2', '3'
...
```

**The output should look like this:** `Client Name`, value contained within `array1` for this `client name`, value contained within `array2` for this `client name` and value contained within `array3` for this client name

**Problem:** I can not perform this operation with 3 arrays, only 2, besides, I am having difficulty formatting the output in the established pattern

**ARRAYS**

```
######################################################################################
# Create arrays
######################################################################################

array1 = [['CLIENT1', '2', '3'],['CLIENT2', '3', '4'],['CLIENT3', '4', '5']]
array2 = [['CLIENT3', '2', '3'],['CLIENT2', '3', '4'],['CLIENT1', '4', '5']]
array3 = [['CLIENT2', '2', '3'],['CLIENT1', '3', '4'],['CLIENT3', '4', '5']]
```

**SEARCH**

```
######################################################################################
# Check and align
######################################################################################

for line1 in array1:
    for line2 in array2:
        if line1[0].upper().__contains__(line2[0].upper()):
            # print of results
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your output should be, I don't understand what you have written there, sorry

Comment: Please clarify how you arrive at the expected output from the given input.  Currently it's not clear.

Comment: The output should look like this: Client Name, value contained within array1 for this client name, value contained within array2 for this client name and value contained within array3 for this client name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using an intermediate dictionary to store the values of every processed client. Using this structure you can store any information from the clients (with repetitions or without) and you can easily parse the output.

Here is the code:

```
# Initialize values
array1 = [['CLIENT1', '2', '3'], ['CLIENT2', '3', '4'], ['CLIENT3', '4', '5']]
array2 = [['CLIENT3', '2', '3'], ['CLIENT2', '3', '4'], ['CLIENT1', '4', '5']]
array3 = [['CLIENT2', '2', '3'], ['CLIENT1', '3', '4'], ['CLIENT3', '4', '5']]

# Initialize a dictionary with key = client name, value = list of client entries
result = {}

# Add values from array1
for client_info in array1:
    # Parse current entry
    client_name = client_info[0]
    client_values = client_info[1:]

    # Add previous values if exitant
    if client_name in result.keys():
        client_values.extend(result[client_name])

    # Update clients dictionary
    result[client_name] = client_values

# Add values from array2
for client_info in array2:
    # Parse current entry
    client_name = client_info[0]
    client_values = client_info[1:]

    # Add previous values if exitant
    if client_name in result.keys():
        client_values.extend(result[client_name])

    # Update clients dictionary
    result[client_name] = client_values

# Add values from array3
for client_info in array3:
    # Parse current entry
    client_name = client_info[0]
    client_values = client_info[1:]

    # Add previous values if exitant
    if client_name in result.keys():
        client_values.extend(result[client_name])

    # Update clients dictionary
    result[client_name] = client_values

# Print result information
for client_name, client_values in result.items():
    print("Result: " + str(client_name) + ", " + str(client_values))
```

And the obtained output:

```
Result: CLIENT1, ['3', '4', '4', '5', '2', '3']
Result: CLIENT2, ['2', '3', '3', '4', '3', '4']
Result: CLIENT3, ['4', '5', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

If you are willing to display ONLY the clients that appear on the 3 lists, you can avoid updating the result dictionary on the `array2` and `array3` loops when the client name is not on the list.

Comment: When trying to use arrays populated by a SELECT from POSTGRES database with lib psycopg2, creating arrays from fetchall (), I got the following output "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'" what can it be?

Comment: @LuisHenrique The `client_values` of each array loop must be a list, not a string. These values are populated from the `client_info` (each entry of the array you presented) so you need to ensure that you create them as a list, not a string. Check this statement: `client_values = client_info[1:]` and ensure that you get a list of string values.

Answer (score 1):

```
array1 = [['CLIENT1', '2', '3'],['CLIENT2', '3', '4'],['CLIENT3', '4', '5']]
array2 = [['CLIENT3', '2', '3'],['CLIENT2', '3', '4'],['CLIENT1', '4', '5']]
array3 = [['CLIENT2', '2', '3'],['CLIENT1', '3', '4'],['CLIENT3', '4', '5']]

def search(key, arrays):
    result = []
    for array in arrays:
        for lst in array:
            if lst[0] == key:
                result.extend(lst[1:])
    return 'Result: {key}, {values}'.format(key=key, values=', '.join(result))

print(search('CLIENT1', (array1, array2, array3)))
```

Output:

```
Result: CLIENT1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4
```